# How to read a jpg bytearray from a Flash AS3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionscript-3

I'm trying to save an image from a Flash AS3 to my server as a jpg file. I found some PHP code to do this, but I want to do this in Ruby. I'm not quite sure how to convert the following code to Ruby. It's mainly the `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` part I don't know how to convert.

```
<?php

   if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {

      // get bytearray $im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

      // save image $f = fopen($_GET['name'], 'wb'); fwrite($f, $jpg); fclose($f);

   } else echo 'An error occured.';

?>
```

source:

http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/

I tried to do the following, but the resulted image file dose not open

```
temp_file = Tempfile.new(['temp', '.jpg'], :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
temp_file.write(request.raw_post)
temp_file.close
```

**EDIT**

The image data is in `request.raw_post`

**EDIT2**

As for the image being sent, here is how the header is created in AS3

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var saveJPG:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:3000/save_image.xml");
saveJPG.requestHeaders.push(header);
```

saveJPG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]
```

can be grabbed from

```
request.env["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]
```

and save it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2571575/643500

**Edit:**

Isn't the image data in `request.body` ?

I need to see how the image is being sent.  Do you have a header with the `Content-Type`?

Comment: so, it shall work like this ?
File.open(tempfile.path,'w') do |f|
       f.write request.env["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]
     end

Comment: You can test it and it will answer the question.  Just debug what you have available.

Comment: The example in the link grabs the image data from the request.

Comment: I need to see how the image is being sent.  Do you have a header with the `Content-Type`?

Comment: try Base64.  If that does not help, then take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/6084208/643500

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the way I post the image, its in multi-part post format now, which is better for paperclip